Spark Version Mismatch error when using synapse.ml.lightgbm
User
I have installed Synapse ML onto databricks cluster from Maven cooradinates com.microsoft.azure:synapseml_2.12:1.0.4 which should support spark 3.4. The DB cluster I have is on runtime version 13.3 LTS ML spark 3.4 scala 2.12.
I import with code
from synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMRegressor import LightGBMRegressor.
But calling  LightGBMRegressor in the NB is giving me error like
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.ml.ComplexParamsWritable.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/ml/ComplexParamsWritable;)
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-878045865667162>, line 3
      1 #!pip install com.microsoft.azure:synapseml_lightgbm_2_12:1.0.4
----> 3 lgbm_cv = LightGBMRegressor()

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/__init__.py:139, in keyword_only.<locals>.wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    137     raise TypeError("Method %s forces keyword arguments." % func.__name__)
    138 self._input_kwargs = kwargs
--> 139 return func(self, **kwargs)


This is happening due to version mismatch but this should not happen because, as per the documentation on the SynapseML's website, Spark cluster should at least have Spark 3.2 and Scala 2.12. text.
Please help me resolve this issue
try:
  from synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMRegressor import LightGBMRegressor
  lgbm_cv = LightGBMRegressor()
except Exception as e:
  print(f"Error encountered: {e}")

